# Multiple gen_esme sessions

Tags: erlang, smpp

Trust you all are doing well.

I am trying to make multiple sessions to SMSC using OSERL application.
Since to make a SMPP client you need to inherit gen_esme behaviour.

I was wondering whether it is possible to make multiple connections towards SMSC without writing multiple gen_esme modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main strategies for starting multiple processes using the same `gen_esme` based module:

1. [`gen_esme:start_link/4`](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl/blob/3.2.4/src/gen_esme.erl#L170-L172) - named or reference based server
2. [`gen_esme:start_link/3`](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl/blob/3.2.4/src/gen_esme.erl#L165-L167) - pid based server

I'm going to be referencing the [`sample_esme`](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl/blob/3.2.4/doc/examples/sample_esme.erl) file found under the [examples for oserl](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl/tree/3.2.4/doc/examples).

#### Named Server

Most of the examples from [oserl](https://github.com/iamaleksey/oserl) show usage of `gen_esme:start_link/4` which in turn is calling [`gen_server:start_link/4`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-4).  The `ServerName` variable for `gen_server:start_link/4` has a typespec of `{local, Name::atom()} | {global, GlobalName::term()} | {via, Module::atom(), ViaName::term()}`.

That means if we change the `sample_esme:start_link/0,1,2` functions to look like this:

```erlang
start_link() ->
    start_link(?MODULE).

start_link(SrvName) ->
    start_link(SrvName, true).

start_link(SrvName, Silent) ->
    Opts = [{rps, 1}, {queue_file, "./sample_esme.dqueue"}],
    gen_esme:start_link({local, SrvName}, ?MODULE, [Silent], Opts).
```

We can start multiple servers using:

```erlang
sample_esme:start_link().           %% SrvName = 'sample_esme'
sample_esme:start_link(my_client1). %% SrvName = 'my_client1'
sample_esme:start_link(my_client2). %% SrvName = 'my_client2'
```

To make our `sample_esme` module work properly with this named server strategy, most of its calling functions will need to be modified.  Let's use `sample_esme:rps/0,1` as an example:

```erlang
rps() ->
    rps(?MODULE).

rps(SrvName) ->
    gen_esme:rps(SrvName).
```

Now we can call the `gen_esme:rps/1` function on any of our running servers:

```erlang
sample_esme:rps().           %% calls 'sample_esme'
sample_esme:rps(my_client1). %% 'my_client1'
sample_esme:rps(my_client2). %% 'my_client2'
```

This is similar to how projects like [pooler](https://github.com/seth/pooler) reference members of pools it creates.

#### pid Server

This is essentially the same as the Named Server strategy, but we're just going to pass the pid of the server around instead of a registered atom.

That means if we change the `sample_esme:start_link/0,1` functions to look like this:

```
start_link() ->
    start_link(true).

start_link(Silent) ->
    Opts = [{rps, 1}, {queue_file, "./sample_esme.dqueue"}],
    gen_esme:start_link(?MODULE, [Silent], Opts).
```

Notice that all we did was drop the `{local, SrvName}` argument so it won't register the `SrvName` atom with the server's pid.

That means we need to capture the pid of each created server:

```erlang
{ok, Pid0} = sample_esme:start_link().
{ok, Pid1} = sample_esme:start_link().
{ok, Pid2} = sample_esme:start_link().
```

Using the same `sample_esme:rps/0,1` example from Named Server, we will need to remove `sample_esme:rps/0` and add a `sample_esme:rps/1` function which takes a pid:

```erlang
rps(SrvPid) ->
    gen_esme:rps(SrvPid).
```

Now we can call the `gen_esme:rps/1` function on any of our running servers:

```erlang
sample_esme:rps(Pid0).
sample_esme:rps(Pid1).
sample_esme:rps(Pid2).
```

This is similar to how projects like [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy) reference members of pools it creates.

#### Recommendations

If you are simply trying to pool connections, I would recommend using a library like [pooler](https://github.com/seth/pooler) or [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy).

If you have a finite number of specifically named connections that you want to reference by name, I would recommend just having a supervisor with a child spec like the following for each connection:

```erlang
{my_client1,
    {sample_esme, start_link, [my_client1]},
    permanent, 5000, worker, [sample_esme]}
```